# How to find all functions that accept level specifications as an argument?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, associations, functional-style, trees

How can I find a list of every function that takes a level specification as an argument?

Answer (score -1):

I learned the answer from a Wolfram U course over the summer.

```
Module[{symbols, symbols2},
 symbols = 
  EntityValue["WolframLanguageSymbol", "TextStrings", 
   "EntityAssociation"];
 symbols2 = 
  CommonName@
   Keys@Select[symbols, 
     AnyTrue[StringContainsQ["levelspec", IgnoreCase -> True]]];
 symbols3 = ToString /@ symbols2;
 Partition[Style[#, 18, "Times"] & /@ symbols3, 5] // Grid]
```

[image]

Comment: -1. This answer is copied from a Wolfram-U course. Acknowledge that in your answer.

Comment: I gave credit for it.